# How to get all the table fields by php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "",$database);
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM area";
$query = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
echo '<pre>';    print_r(mysqli_fetch_array($query));
```

the above is my code it is returning only the id(first field)

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:** my bad, sorry.

As shown in the [MySQLi examples on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php), you want to iter through the results; your code would look like:

```
$link = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", $database);
$cursor = $link->query('SHOW COLUMNS FROM area;');
while ($row = $cursor->fetch_assoc())
{
  print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 6
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 5
    [type] => 0
)

Comment: Edited, sorry for the poor answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch all rows like this

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "",$database);
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM area";
$query = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
echo '<pre>';
while ($res = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    print_r($res); 
}
echo '</pre>';
```